# What's the meaning of the word "walinemos"?

Tags: traducción, significado

It's in this phrase:

> **Walinemos** in honor a nuestros abuelitos

This is a phrase from an "Ícaro" (traditional medicines songs). The complete lyrics is this:

> LOS VERDADEROS CURANDEROS
>
> Las verdaderas curanderas yo me supongo
>   hayan sido esas abuelas que trajeron medicina
>
> Luego escogieron las plantitas
>   Mama Wilca, Ayahuasca
>   Wachumita, Chacrunita / Nakaikuna, Jicurito
>   Toe, Coca y Sairi
>
> Por qué, por qué muy alegres
>   Por qué, por qué no muy tristes
>
> **Walinemos** en honor a nuestros abuelitas
>
> Los verdaderos curanderos yo me supongo
>   Hayan sido esos abuelos que trajeron ceremonia
>
> Luego escogieron las plantitas
>   Mama Wilca, Ayahuasca
>   Wachumita, Chacrunita / Nakaikuna, Jicurito
>   Toe, Coca y Sairi
>
> Por qué, por qué muy alegres
>   Por qué, por qué no muy tristes
>   Walinemos en honor a nuestras abuelitos
>
> La verdadera curandera yo estoy seguro
>   haya sido Pachamama que nos dio sus medicinas
>
> Luego nos brindó sus plantitas
>   Mama Wilca, Ayahuasca
>   Wachumita, Chacrunita / Nakaikuna, Jicurito
>   Toe, Coca y Sairi
>
> Por qué, por qué muy alegres
>   Por qué, por qué no muy tristes
>   Walinemos en honor a nuestra Pachamama

Video of the song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlN-kfxVLxU

Based on this the answer that "walinemos" is a form for "bailemos" seem to make sense. Can someone confirm and/or explain where this form originated ?

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]. Maybe you should check the [tour] and [help] sections to understand better the philosophy of this site. When you ask, is a good idea to show previous research effort. You should give some context too. Was that in a chat? My guess is that it is "bailemos" instead of "walinemos" (typo or similar). See some of the other questions for more insight about formatting, how to write a good question etc. If you need help feel free to ask via comments or in [meta]. We are here to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diego's answer isn't too far off.  The word does indeed mean *dance*, more or less, but it doesn't come from *bailar*.

The specific line comes from a song, *Las verdaderas curanderas* (which I believe is written by Kike Pinto but that may be bad information from the internet)

> Por qué, por qué muy alegres,
>   por qué, por qué no muy tristes
>   **<sup>Walinemos/</sup>/<sub>Hualinemos</sub>** en honor a <sup>nuestros abuelitos</sup>/<sub>nuestra Pachamama</sub>

The *hu-* traditionally used to transcribe Quechua words is now generally spelt *w-* in modern orthography.

According to a [Licentiate thesis](http://cybertesis.unmsm.edu.pe/bitstream/cybertesis/593/1/Rengifo_ce.pdf) by Elías Rengifo de la Cruz, the word *hualina* refers to songs and the dances that accompany them:

> la hualina es canto y danza cuya referencia principal es el agua y todo acontecer emocional o social que tenga que ver con ella. (p. 66)

The author cites Rosario Olivas Weston's book  *Marcahuasi, mito y realidad. Un manual de información para visitar el pueblo de San Pedro de Casta y la meseta de Marcahuasi* which makes specific reference to the verb:

> Hualinar es la acción de bailar las hualinas, dando vueltas alrededor de las Mayoralas, Cantor y Abanderado, en una u otra dirección, simbolizando los remolinos que se forman en las acequias. (p. 62 originally, p. 65 in the thesis)

Thus, the particular line could be translated as follows

> <sup>May we</sup>/<sub>Let us</sub> sing and dance in honor of our grandmothers

while recognizing that the song and dance is a special one with particular relation to the *yaku raymi* (or *water festival/fiesta del agua*).

Comment: By the way, do know what is the "Nakaikuna" mentioned in the lyrics ?

Comment: @nelsonteixeira I believe it is a plant of some sort. Alternatively it could be an local figure

Comment: Found it. "Nakaikuna" it's magic mushrooms.